# Passing two columns into keyBy() Spark

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala. I am reading the .csv in spark. I want to apply `keyBy()` on two columns. Any idea.

Say `column _(0)` and `_(1)`

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the RDD to which you want to apply `keyBy` is an RDD of Arrays. Then you can simply supply the `keyBy` method with the function mapping to the first two columns:

```
val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(
             Array(1,2,3),
             Array(1,2,4),
             Array(2,3,1),
             Array(2,3,2)
         ))
val keyedRdd=rdd.keyBy{a=>(a(0),a(1))}
keyedRdd.take(4)
//Array[((Int, Int), Array[Int])] = Array(
//           ((1,2),Array(1, 2, 3)), 
//           ((1,2),Array(1, 2, 4)), 
//           ((2,3),Array(2, 3, 1)), 
//           ((2,3),Array(2, 3, 2))
//)
```